# Script to select which result/value to be copied to a text file using AWK

Tags: bash, scripting

Can someone help me with the last step in my bash script.
You helped me already getting this far.

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f \
       -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' \
    -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mov' |
while read -r file
do 
    size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
    duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file")
    codec=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file")
    ratio=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $size / $duration")
    echo "$file: codec=$codec, size=$size, duration=$duration, ratio=$ratio" | tee -a /home/user/Downloads/logfile
    printf $ratio | awk '{print $1/1000}'| tee -a /home/user/Downloads/logfile
done
```

Now ALL results go to the text file.
But is there a way to select only the files with a ratio bigger than ...?

As requested by @markp-fuso, I clarified a few points:

> *please update the question with some samples of what's in $ratio*

In the $ratio are numbers generated from dividing the video file size in bytes with the duration of the videofile in seconds. These are numbers around 50k to 1000k. Therefore I use awk '{print $1/1000}'to bring them more in the range of 50 - 1000.

> *and what you're thinking of using as a cutoff/threshold; are you
> looking to filter based on a) the value in $ratio, b) the value
> generated by awk or c) the result of the numfmt call?*

Good points, I had in mind to use the numfmt call to bring the bytes up to megabytes. But that is redunded. So that can be deleted and I hereby did.
It works up to the point that it generates the wanted outcome:

```
./file1.mp4: codec=h264
aac, size=54886926, duration=94.900000, ratio=578365.92
578.366
./file2.mp4: codec=vp9
aac, size=15147100, duration=108.159000, ratio=140044.74
140.045
./file3.mp4: codec=vp9
aac, size=22306731, duration=109.947000, ratio=202886.21
202.886
```

I will use this to find the video/audio files can be encoded/shrink-ed as they are large for their duration time.
So a high $ratio can possible be encoded.The value can easily be adjusted in the script, but it will be around 200-400.
Depending on the codec efficiency (I just added a line to display the used codec also).

So in the end I like to have a text file with only those files that do make the requirements, in this case a bigger than set ratio.I will than make a decision based on experience.

Note: *If possible, it would be great if files that can not be read (eg. due to being corrupted), so without any value, will be added to the text file.*

Let's assume I set the ratio to 200, than the txt file should contain the following, based on the 3 examples above:

```
./file1.mp4: codec=h264
aac, size=54886926, duration=94.900000, ratio=578365.92
578.366
./file3.mp4: codec=vp9
aac, size=22306731, duration=109.947000, ratio=202886.21
202.886
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: please update the question with some samples of what's in `$ratio` and what you're thinking of using as a cutoff/threshold; are you looking to filter based on *a)* the value in `$ratio`, *b)* the value generated by `awk` or *c)* the result of the `numfmt` call?

Comment: @markp-fuso, thnx for your reply. I edited the original post responding to your questions.

Comment: you've provided 3 sample ratios and the outputs from `awk`; you've also stated using a cutoff/threshold of 200-400; let's pick 200 as the cutoff/threshold ... what is the expected contents of `logfile` (corresponding to the 3 sample ratios/awk-outputs)?

Comment: @markp-fuso
added the wanted/expected text file content.

Comment: so `codec` values include an embedded linefeed (eg, `h264 \n aac`)?

Comment: @markp-fuso: It doesn't matter how they are displayed as long as the ratio used for evaluation is on a separate line for quick viewing, If that's what you mean? So in this case 578 and the 202 on a separate line.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, the output of the `ffprobe` command that returns codecs can have embedded newlines. Dave999, this sort of thing is why we asked for examples. You described the content of `$ratio` for example, but you didn't show it. When we ask for clarification, show, don't tell. Often, if you tell, you are telling us what you _think_ is in a variable,but you could be wrong. Also, we need to see it. Things like the codec command output including newlines are important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various issues in your script that you should fix before addressing the point you're asking about. First, your `find` command is wrong and second, this will fail on file names containing newline characters.

Your `find` is wrong because you aren't grouping the options. This means that your command will also find directories whose name ends in e.g. `.mov`. Consider this directory:

```
$ ls -lF
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon    0 Mar 18 18:37 'a bad'$'\n''file name.mp4'
drwxr-xr-x 2 terdon terdon 4096 Mar 18 18:38  foo.mov/
```

That contains one file, whose name has spaces and a newline, and one directory, `foo.mov`. You only want to process the files, but your `find` will also return the directory:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mov' 
./foo.mov
./a bad?file name.mp4
```

You want the `-type f` to apply to all conditions, and to do that, you need to group them as [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772555/22222) to your previous question mentioned:

```
$ find . -type f \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mov' \)
./a bad?file name.mp4
```

As you can see above, grouping them with parentheses (they need to be escaped as `\(` or quoted `'('` to protect them from the shell) makes the command find only files, as desired. The next issue is the newlines. You can address this by telling `find` to print its results separated with a NULL (`\0`) byte instead of a newline. GNU `find`, the default on Linux systems, can do this with `-print0`, and with other find implementations, you can use `-printf`.

Here is the error if you don't handle such names:

```
$ find . -type f \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mov' \) | while read -r file; do ls -l "$file"; done
ls: cannot access './a bad': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'file name.mp4': No such file or directory
```

And here's how to get it right:

```
$ find . -type f \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mov' \) -print0 | while read -r -d '' file; do ls -l "$file"; done
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 Mar 18 18:37 './a bad'$'\n''file name.mp4'
```

The `IFS=` isn't essential here, but it is good practice to use it. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480210/1081936) for an example of why, the real job is done by the `-d ''` option to `read` which tells `read` to use NULL as the input deliminator.

Finally, you also need to be able to handle more than one codec returned since that seems quite common, at least with the files I tested with. For example:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 foo.mkv 
hevc
ac3
ass
```

So pass the output of the `ffprobe` command through `tr '\n' ','` or something to remove the newlines:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 foo.mkv | tr '\n' ','
hevc,ac3,ass,$
```

(That final `$` is my prompt, shown there to indicate there is no trailing newline here.)

Now, all that said, since you have the ratio in a variable already, all you need is a simple `if` to check if it is above your threshold. I don't understand why you have two ratios (`$ratio` and `$ratio / 1000`), it seems more reasonable to me to only use the one you're actually testing, but that's your call. Here's a working script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

threshold=$1
if [ -z "$threshold" ]; then
  echo "No threshold given, using the default value of 200" >&2
  threshold=200
fi

logfile="/home/user/Downloads/logfile"

find . -type f \
  \( -name '*.mp4' -o -name '*.mkv' -o \
     -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mov' \) -print0 | 
 while IFS= read -r -d '' file
 do 
    size=$(stat -c %s "$file")
    duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration \
                       -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file")
    codec=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=codec_name \
                    -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file" |
              tr '\n' ',')
    ratio=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $size / $duration")

    # Check that a ratio was found, otherwise print an error
    if [[ -z "$ratio" ]]; then
      echo "No ratio found for '$file'" >&2
    else
      ## Not sure why you want two separate values for ratio but...
      ratio2=$(bc <<< "$ratio / 1000")

      if [[ $ratio2 -ge $threshold ]]; then
        printf '%s: codec=%s size=%s, duration=%s, ratio=%s\n' \
               "$file" "$codec" "$size" "$duration" "$ratio" | tee -a "$logfile"
        echo "$ratio2" | tee -a "$logfile"
      fi
    fi
done
```

You would now run it with the threshold as an argument (or with no argument to default to 200):

```
script.sh 300
```

I also made some other minor, mostly aesthetic, changes to the script, as well as adding some basic error handling, but it should do exactly the same thing. The output looks like:

```
$ foo.sh 200
./file3.mkv: codec=h264,aac, size=764948534, duration=3488.131000, ratio=219300.40
219
./file7.mkv: codec=h264,aac, size=739550128, duration=3542.852000, ratio=208744.29
208
./file5.mkv: codec=h264,aac, size=688337512, duration=3439.637000, ratio=200119.23
200
./file1.mkv: codec=h264,aac, size=883534591, duration=3701.386000, ratio=238703.71
238
./file4.mkv: codec=h264,aac, size=828112726, duration=3769.898000, ratio=219664.49
219
```

Comment: wow, took me 2 days to come to my noob solution. Thanks a million. Looks great, and shows me what a noob I still am. Just one more question, how to print size in MB and duration in minutes?  For the size I added a line: 'sizeMB=$((size / 1024 /1024))' , that works. However I can not get the time to minutes. I tried adding a line after the defining  the duration, this line being: 'durationMIN=$((duration / 60))'

Comment: @dave999 The shell can't do floating point arithmetic, so use the same approach as you already do elsewhere: pass to `bc` or `awk` and save as a variable. Something like `durationMIN=$(bc <<< "$duration / 6")`. For next time, please try and put all of the requirements in the question. I know it's not always possible, but it makes your life (and ours) easier. Think about the final objective, and describe that so we know what the script is supposed to do.

Comment: Thnx again and I will do as you said next time! Learned a lot last few days. For now, have a nice evening!

Comment: You too, @dave999, and I know how you feel, that (learning loads in a short time) was my initial reaction when I first found this site too! :)

Answer (score 2):

Likely near the top, declare your cutoff value:

```
# We only care about files with ratios GREATER than this:
cutoff=200000
```

Then near the bottom of your `while` loop, wrap the `echo` and `printf` commands with a test and an `if` statement:

```
    ...
    ratio=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $size / $duration")
    rc=$(bc <<< "$ratio > $cutoff")
    if [[ "$rc" == "1" ]]
    then {
        echo "$file: codec=$codec, size=$size, duration=$duration, ratio=$ratio"
        awk '{print $1/1000}' <<< "$ratio"
    } | tee -a /home/user/Downloads/logfile
    fi
done
```

Comment: Great! That works. Thnx. Just a last question, would it be possible to add files to the text file that can not be read (eg. due to being corrupted), so without any value or showing an error?

Comment: @dave999 please do note the now two separate answers that have pointed out a problem with your `find` command. As for adding the values, yes it is easy. It should be trivial to add an echo to my script in cases where `ratio` is empty since I'm already testing for that. Use that as your guide. But please fix the other issues.